# Computing the integral of a differential form in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $D$ be the disk
\begin{equation}
D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\:|\:x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1\},
\end{equation}
which is easily verified to be a compact $2$-differentiable manifold with boundary.

Let $d\omega$ be the $2$-differential form on $D$ given by
\begin{equation}
d\omega=(1-x^{2})\:dx\wedge dy.
\end{equation}

I want to compute the following integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{D}d\omega
\end{equation}

How can I do that? I don't really understand how to parametrize $D$ in order to keep the standard orientation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, which is given by the canonical basis ordered as $[e_{1},\:e_{2}]$.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be easier to use polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.

Comment: Can you write what the beggining of the expression would be? I am getting really confused with doing polar coordinates all at once, before finding a parametrization for $D$, I don't know what I should to with the pullback to match it up. This even without taking in account the orientation problem

Comment: It is really the double integral $\int_D (1-x^2)dxdy$. Do you know how to calculate this?

Comment: Take it a step at a time: You know that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Compute the pullbacks of $dx$ and $dy$, and once you have those, $dx\wedge dy$. The new region is obvious, and the pullback of $1-x^2$ should be easy to work out. Plug all of that into your integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the polar transform $\phi(x,y) =\big(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta)\big)$ and find the pullback of $d\omega$ under this mapping.

$$\phi^*dx = d(r\cos(\theta)) = \frac{\partial r\cos(\theta)}{\partial r}dr + \frac{\partial r\cos(\theta)}{\partial \theta}d\theta = \cos(\theta)dr-r\sin(\theta)d\theta \\ \phi^*dy = d(r\sin(\theta)) = \sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta \\ \begin{align}\implies \phi^*d\omega &= \phi^*\left[(1-x^{2})\ dx\wedge dy\right] \\ &= \big[1-r^2\cos^2(\theta)\big]\ \big(\cos(\theta)dr-r\sin(\theta)d\theta\big)\wedge \big(\sin(\theta)dr + r\cos(\theta)d\theta\big) \\ &= \big[1-r^2\cos^2(\theta)\big]r\ dr\wedge d\theta\end{align}$$

Then $$\int_D d\omega = \int_D (1-x^2)\ dx\wedge dy = \int_{\phi^{-1}(D)} \big[1-r^2\cos^2(\theta)\big]r\ dr\wedge d\theta = \int_{\phi^{-1}(D)} \phi^*d\omega$$

The only thing left is to find $\phi^{-1}(D)$.  In this case it's pretty obvious that it's $\phi^{-1}(D) = \{(r,\theta) \mid 0 \le r \le 1, 0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi\}$.  This is a simple region (actually it's just a rectangle) in the $r$-$\theta$ plane.  So using Fubini's theorem we can see that this integral can be written as an iterated integral:

$$\int_{\phi^{-1}(D)} \big[1-r^2\cos^2(\theta)\big]r\ dr\wedge d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \big[1-r^2\cos^2(\theta)\big]r\ drd\theta$$

This integral is then rather simple to evaluate.